# HTML5 video background only responsive with position:fixed; however I don't want it to scroll with the page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html5-video

So, I have something like this, a decent somewhat responsive html5 background:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNrdpV

```
<style>
.video {
  position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    -moz-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    -o-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    -ms-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best

    overflow: hidden;
}

.margin {
  margin-top: 400px;
}

</style>
<video id="my-video" class="video" muted loop autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!-- 
  <source src="media/demo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="media/demo.webm" type="video/webm"> -->
</video>  
<h1 class="margin"> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1><h1> Some Content</h1><h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1><h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
<h1> Some Content</h1>
```

So, my problem is, that if I change position:fixed to position:absolute it will become non-responsive. However, I dont want the video to scroll with the page...
What to do?
The other positions like position:static are a mess.

If you change the position from fixed, you can see a vertical scrollbar appear upon smaller screen sizes.

EDIT:
The problem is only visible on codepen if you change its layout/view to 'Right', so the HTML/CSS/Java boxes are on the right side and the preview is on the left(not the initial top and bottom layout). Weird.

Comment: What do you mean by responsive ?

Comment: Check the codepen. Change the position:fixed; to position:absolute; and you can see a horizontal scrollbar appears when you resize the window.

Comment: Not in my browser ^^, which browser do you use ?

Comment: Ohh its only visible on codepen if you change its layout to 'Right', so the HTML/CSS/Java boxes are on the right side and the preview is on the left(and not the initial top/bottom layout). Weird. Anyways, it behaves the same way on the webpage I'm developing too

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do all of the heavy-lifting of creating a responsive video element yourself, use the [FitVids.js](http://fitvidsjs.com/) plugin to do it for you, it does exactly what you need.